# What's the difference between a general linear model and a generalized linear model?

Tags: definition, regression, linear-regression, regression-analysis

I need to use a model for my Master's thesis. Looking beyond multiple linear regression, I have found extensions like the ***general* linear model**, and the ***generalized* linear model**. What is the difference between those?

For what I understood from Wikipedia:

- A [multiple linear regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression#Simple_and_multiple_linear_regression) is a linear model, **with 1 output and multiple inputs**
- A [general linear model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_linear_model) is a system of multiple linear models, i.e. a (usually matrix) model **with multiple outputs**
- A [generalized linear model (GLM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_linear_model) is an extension of the usual linear model, both simple (one input) and multiple (multiple inputs), where **we expect the residuals to follow a distribution not normal**, but of any function in the exponential family.

Therefore, there can be models that are only GLM (one output, non normal error), only general (multiple output, normal error), or both (multiple output, non normal error). Moreover, all of the above may have one single input (simple regression), or multiple ones (multivariate/multiple inputs).

Is this right?

Comment: 1. Read the [links](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_linear_model#Comparison_to_generalized_linear_model) that you are posting. 2. Better ask on stats stackexchange .

Comment: I've read the links, it just seemed strange to me using so similar terms for different things. I was basically looking for a confirmation. However, I searched for a statistics SE and didn't find it, thanks for pointing it out! 